# How to automatically detect users who had logged in and head them to dashboard page without them logging in again in Ionic 4 and firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I have a project in Ionic 4 and firebase. I don't want users to usually login every time they use the app. It should be automatic logins. What should I do to achieve this?

Here is my login page code.
login.page.html

```
<ion-content padding>
 <div class="ion-text-center">
   <h2>Login</h2>
 </div>
 <ion-item>
   <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

 <ion-item>
   <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

 <ion-button color="danger" expand="block" (click)="loginUser()">Login</ion-button>
 <ion-button color="primary" expand="block" (click)="gotoRegister()">Register</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

login.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  email: string = ""
  password: string =""
  constructor(private router: Router, public afauth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async loginUser(){
    const {email, password} = this
    try {
      const res = this.afauth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    } catch(err){
      console.dir(err)
      if(err.code === "auth/user-not-found"){
        console.log("User not found")
      }
    }


  }

  gotoRegister(){
    this.router.navigate(['/register']);
  }
}
```

Comment: store usr's credential in secure place like app preference and next time check if already stored then send credential to server to authenticate and route user to dashboard.

Comment: How can I achieve that?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-preferences use this plugin to encrypt and decrypt.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement using new feature ionic 4 Guards
As below
After login success set status
`this.storage.set('seen-intro', true);`

and below code changes in guards file

```
async canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
      let introSeen = await this.storage.get('seen-intro');

      if (!introSeen) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/intro');
      }
      return introSeen;
}
```

more information follow this [more info](https://www.joshmorony.com/prevent-access-to-pages-in-ionic-with-angular-route-guards/)

Comment: what is guard here. i can't see any this such

Comment: https://www.joshmorony.com/prevent-access-to-pages-in-ionic-with-angular-route-guards/

Comment: You can also  check using firebase `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});`

Comment: I found a different way of doing this. The only issue with it is that for a returning user the app takes few seconds before redirecting them to the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different solution to this. The only problem is that returning users do not get redirected instantly to dashboard. It takes up to 10secs before it redirects them. How can I make it much effective?

I used this in my very first page.ts

```
constructor(private router: Router, public afauth: AngularFireAuth) { 
    this.afauth.authState.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
      if (!user) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }else
      {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }
      return;
    });
  }
```